# How to add distinct to a string concat via for xml type query

Tags: sql-server, for-xml-path

I have a query which works well except that it doesn't return unique values, but repeats some.

If the columns of the query were independent and not part of a string concatenation I am able to add `distinct` as long as I also add each item in the `select` to the `order by` clause, which is what you would expect.

The complication comes when I use a concatenated string (as presented here) because, by design, if I add a `distinct` to the `select`, SQL Server will complain that one needs to include each `order by` item in the select and vice versa, but how does one do that when a string concat via `for xml` is being done? That is where I am stuck.

I tried various incantations and haven't landed on anything that works with the string concatenation scheme I have presented here.

Unfortunately I must return the data concatenated as presented here as that data must appear all in one column which is later consumed by some SQLCLR code.

So again, the `select` needs a `distinct` keyword, but in this current form, SQL Server will need some adjustments before it will accept it.

(Also note that the code is part of a larger query so the alias and the ending comma can be removed and a select added to the beginning and `@Warehouses` and `s.itemcode` can be declared as variables in a test environment which is how I've tested various [failed] approaches.)

My sense is that some SQL Server XML skills might be needed or turning this into a subquery with an outer query that somehow picks up the now unique subquery columns and concatenates them.

Any ideas?

```
coalesce(stuff((select '; ' + convert(nvarchar, t0.docnum) + ': '
                    + convert(nvarchar, t0.duedate, 101) + ', '
                    + convert(nvarchar, convert(int, t0.plannedqty))
                from owor t0
                inner join wor1 t1 on t0.docentry = t1.docentry
                where t0.status in ('P','R')
                  and t1.warehouse in (select value from string_split(@Warehouses,','))
                  and t0.itemcode = s.itemcode
                order by t0.duedate
                for xml path(''), type).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, N''), N'') as p_pros_data,
```

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edit your question

Comment: Use a `GROUP BY` (on your columns) instead.

Comment: @ThomA please make your comment an answer so that I may accept it. It worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`distinct` is in any case often less efficient when used on calculated columns, as it cannot use indexes.

So just use a `group by` instead

```sql
coalesce(
  stuff((
    select '; ' + convert(nvarchar(30), o.docnum) + ': '
                + convert(nvarchar(30), o.duedate, 101) + ', '
                + convert(nvarchar(30), convert(int, o.plannedqty))
    from owor o
    inner join wor1 w1 on o.docentry = w1.docentry
    where o.status in ('P','R')
      and w1.warehouse in (select value from string_split(@Warehouses,','))
      and o.itemcode = s.itemcode
    group by
      o.docnum,
      o.duedate,
      o.plannedqty
    order by
      o.duedate
    for xml path(''), type
    ).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, N''
  ),
  N'') as p_pros_data,
```

If you have SQL Server 2017+ available, you can use the much more efficient `STRING_AGG` function. You still need to group separately, because there is no `DISTINCT` modifier, it's also more efficient as mentioned.

```sql
coalesce(
  (
    select string_agg(convert(nvarchar(30), o.docnum) + ': '
                + convert(nvarchar(30), o.duedate, 101) + ', '
                + convert(nvarchar(30), convert(int, o.plannedqty)),
           '; ')
               within group (order by t0.duedate)
    from (
        select
          o.docnum,
          o.duedate,
          o.plannedqty
        from owor o
        inner join wor1 w1 on o.docentry = w1.docentry
        where o.status in ('P','R')
          and w1.warehouse in (select value from string_split(@Warehouses,','))
          and o.itemcode = s.itemcode
        group by
          o.docnum,
          o.duedate,
          o.plannedqty
    ) o
  ),
  N'') as p_pros_data,
```

Comment: Thank you for the string_agg formulation.